# can't control on audio from control center in swift

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, controls, center

i have an issue with the control center i need to control on audio playback from background through control center i set the following code :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
            mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [
                MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:arrayOfUrl[index].lastPathComponent,
                MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:"Collection Of Audios"
            ]
}
```

and i receive the control events from the

```
override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?)
```

and i set the following code

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

everything is good and works the problem is only i can control on my audio from control center if i playing one music and from this music i exit from the app in this situation i can control on the audio like play ,pause , next , and so on but if i try to control on audio from control center from another page through the app the control center not responding for the next,previous where the mistake from my code, please help  to make control center responding on my events from everywhere in my app like i playing the audio and i exit from page audio and the audio currently playing and exit from the app from that page

thank you very much

Comment: can i ask you how you made that first i want to know how to control my app music throw control center and notification but i uses `avaudioplayer `  and `streemingKit ` framwork

Answer (score 0):

this post is too old but maybe this could help someone.
you can add this method to your class :

```
//*****************************************************************
// MARK: - Remote Command Center Controls
//*****************************************************************

func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
    // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
        //Do stuff here or play your mediaPlayer
        return .success
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
        //Do stuff here or pause your mediaPlayer
        return .success
    }

    // Add handler for Next Command
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
        //Do stuff 
        return .success
    }

    // Add handler for Previous Command
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
        //Do stuff 
        return .success
    }
}
```

Then call the method in your onCreate method :

```
// Setup Remote Command Center
    setupRemoteCommandCenter()
```